# Difference between "formatting" and "styling" when used with documents

Tags: word-choice

For example one may say:

"This document is well formatted" or "This document is well styled" - What are the differences here, if any?

What about the task: "formatting" or "styling", are these usable in this context or should I use another word?

Comment: What do you know about the difference between the underlying verbs *format* and *style*, if there is any? Does the meaning of the corresponding nouns add anyting to your understanding?

Comment: Well, AFAIK, both verb mean to apply some rules of presentation to a document, for example, having titles in bold, and paragraphs in block text. In my perception format seems somewhat more technical, and style somewhat more free (artful), but with the question I want to ask if this is commonly perceived as such.

Comment: @Marcel, I agree  -  that comment could be an answer.